# form input to javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I don't understand what the problem is, I'm left confused. I assume the problem might be very simple as I am new to PHP.

**My form:**

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                        <label>Name</label>
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Email Address -->
                        <div class="row control-group">
                        <label>Email Address</label>
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Home Location -->
                        <div class="row control-group">
                        <label>Home Location</label>
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Home Location" id="homelocation" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your home location.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Phone Number -->
                        <div class="row control-group">
                        <label>Phone Number</label>
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <div class="row control-group">
                        <label>How did you hear about us?</label><br>
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <select name="advert" <!-- To configure -->>
                              <option value="google">Google Search</option>
                              <option value="trademe">Trademe</option>
                            </select>
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**JS:**

```
submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
    // Prevent spam click and default submit behaviour
    $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", true);
    event.preventDefault();

    // get values from FORM
    var name = $("input#name").val();
    var email = $("input#email").val();

    var phone = $("input#phone").val();
    var homelocation = $("input#homelocation").val();
    ....
    $.ajax({
            url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: name,
                phone: phone,
                email: email,
                homelocation: homelocation,
                .........
```

and my **php:**

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['homelocation'])    ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$homelocation = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['homelocation']));
..............
```

The code works perfectly fine if I comment out `homelocation`, I have no idea why.

I am new to PHP so I am a bit confused as to why the above code doesn't work, but if `homelocation` is commented out, then it works. The name and `homelocation` have the same input type, so I don't think data type has anything to do with it, and I am sure the variable names are used correctly, could someone please point me to the right direction on this one.

Thanks!

Comment: Check `homelocation` pass or not in console

Comment: What type of values are you getting from `homelocation` field?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I am testing homelocation with a simple string,

Comment: @NikhilVaghela I tested it in console, and it seems to be empty. I am getting closer to a solution :) thanks

Comment: Does it return `empty` or `null`? You have this field `empty($_POST['homelocation'])` You may want to pass default value if `homelocation` is empty.

Comment: It is empty, I don't understand why it would be empty because when I test it, I fill the homelocation field. The issue seems to be with JS handling the input. I will look for a solution there. I still don't get it though, because the other fields are obtained without any issues.

Comment: Try adding a line after `var homelocation` something similar to `if( homelocation == "" ) homelocation = "homelocation";` and report back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127936/discussion-between-almost-a-beginner-and-aniket-sahrawat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem with your html tags. You can check for errors in html document [here](https://html5.validator.nu/). Just fix those errors and it will work just fine.